# Configurable product does not have sub-products magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, exception, magento-2.1.1

I am facing one problem with the configurable product.
I am using Magento 2.1.1 and when i open category page than it throws me below error.

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Configurable product "red-wine-liqueur-vinegar" does not have
>   sub-products
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException):
>   Configurable product "red-wine-liqueur-vinegar" does not have
>   sub-products
>       #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\m2migration\demo\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Pricing\Price\ConfigurableRegularPrice.php(71):
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver->resolvePrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
>   When i am edit this configurable product from admin than it shows
>   "Requested product doesn't exist".

Let me know if by using any query or programmatically we can resolve the issue.

Comment: For your configurable product with no sub product is added so its issue are coming. first check for your config product have assigned simple product or not, if not then first assigned simple product with it.

Comment: Hello @Rakesh, Thanks for our answer. I am unable to edit that configurable product from admin. It throws error like "Requested product doesn't exist"

Comment: Were you changing something in catalog programmatically or what was the last change you did made this issue occur.

Comment: Hello @mp196, I have migrated data from 1.7 to 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this has been a magento issue after migration. Please check the link [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4255#issuecomment-221259199). It might be solution to your question.